# Access VBA - FindFirst can't find a code that really exists

Tags: vba, ms-access

The first one is supposed to be able to find all the codes that have at least the string written in the control, but it does not work at all.

The second one works fine, but only search for the specific string and that's all.

I think this is just a problem of misspelling and thats all but I cant find the way after several hours. Any help?

```
        lentes.FindFirst "codigo = '" & "*" & Me!LenD & "*" & "' and active = true and tipo = 'montes'"

        lentes.FindFirst "codigo = '" & Me!LenD & "'" & " and active = true" & " and tipo = 'montes'"
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
lentes.FindFirst "codigo = '*" & Me!LenD & "*' and active = true and tipo = 'montes'"
```

Should probably be something like this:

```
lentes.FindFirst "codigo LIKE '*" & Me!LenD & "*' and active = true and tipo = 'montes'"
```

Otherwise you're looking for a value that literally has an asterix at the beginning and end.  Using LIKE means that it'll search for a pattern, not a literal value.

Answer (score 0):

When you use wildcards (first expression) you are not checking equality: therefore instead of = you need to use LIKE.